# Web Scraping Using Beautiful Soup (prints data group listed into one cell instead of across individual cells)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Trying to get the "all splits" line of numbers from https://insider.espn.com/nba/player/splits/_/id/532/type/nba/year/2003/category/perGame and webpages like it to all be in their own cell across the row in a csv file. currently prints listed into one cell.
Ideal format would be

| Name | Year | PER # | GP | Min | etc.. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name | 2003 | Per# | 75 | 39.4 |  |

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import pandas as pd


names_list = ["name", "lots", "of", "names", "defined", "earlier"]  # names of players
pers = ['Per#', "lots", "of", "PER numbers (integers) ", "defined", "earlier"]  # player efficency ratings
statsurls = ['https://insider.espn.com/nba/player/splits/_/id/532/type/nba/year/2003/category/perGame']  # 100s of players pages in this same format (found by going through the 'id/#' and 'year/#')
statslist = []


def GetStats(statsurl):
    statsreq = requests.get(statsurl)
    statssoup = BeautifulSoup(statsreq.text, 'lxml')
    t = statssoup.select('main#fittPageContainer div.Table__Scroller > table > tbody')
    all_splits = [h.text for h in t[0].find_all('tr')[1].find_all('td')]
    split_list = [elem.split() for elem in all_splits]
    statslist.append(split_list)

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    RunStats = [executor.submit(GetStats, statsurl) for statsurl in statsurls]


names_stats = pd.DataFrame(zip(names_list, pers, statslist))
names_stats.to_csv('names&stats.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: The desired output isn't too clear, you only want the row under "all_splits"?

Comment: desired output would be the data in that row within an individual column, while also having name and PER data in the same row

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that `names_list` and `pers` are flat lists but `statslist` is list of lists, so just zipping the 3 together directly results in a list of tuples like

```py
[
  (name0, pers0, all_splits_0_LIST),
  (name1, pers1, all_splits_1_LIST),
  (name2, pers2, all_splits_2_LIST),
  ## AND SO ON...
]
```

instead you might want to do something like

```py
names_stats = pd.DataFrame([tuple([n, p] + s) for n, p, s in zip(names_list, pers, statslist)])
```

---

I don't think zipping separately obtained lists together is the best way to ensure that the right data is matched up to the right name...wouldn't it be be more reliable to get the name and person# from `statssoup` and `statsurl`?

```py
def GetStats(statsurl):
    statsreq = requests.get(statsurl)
    statssoup = BeautifulSoup(statsreq.text, 'lxml')
    t = statssoup.select('main#fittPageContainer div.Table__Scroller > table > tbody')
    all_splits = [h.text for h in t[0].find_all('tr')[1].find_all('td')]
    split_list = [elem.split() for elem in all_splits]

    pers = statsurl.split('/id/', 1)[-1].split('.', 1)[0]
    yr = statsurl.split('/year/', 1)[-1].split('.', 1)[0]
    # name = statssoup.select_one('h1.PlayerHeader__Name').get_text(' ').strip() # not as safe as:
    name = ' '.join([n.get_text(' ').strip() for n in statssoup.select('h1.PlayerHeader__Name') if n.get_text().strip()])
    statslist.append([name, yr, pers] + split_list)
```

and then you can just form the DataFrame with **`names_stats = pd.DataFrame(statslist)`**.